# Excel equations subject to data

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I have run into an Excel brick wall and need some inspiration. I have a spreadsheet where pressures could be added in a variety of units and i want to calculate the outputs in mBar. I have tried nesting IF statements such as:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(K22),"",SUM(K22*1013.25)),IF(ISBLANK(M22),"",SUM(M22*33.8639)),IF(ISBLANK(O22),"",SUM(O22*1.33322))
```

[image: What im trying to acheive]

but this returns an error.

Ideally what i want is the user to be able to enter data in any cell (relative to the measurement) such as ATM in K22 and output mBar in Q22?

The other way i suppose i could do it is leave the input cell blank and just calculate a range of outputs but that isnt as neat and i open to user error, such as Bar or mBar, inHg or mmHg etc..

Comment: Can you add some sample data or a screenshot, as well as the expected result, to your question?

Comment: My guess is that K22,M22, and/or O22 are filled by another formula.  ISBLANK returns `FALSE` if there is a formula that returns `""`.  And then when you try to multiply `""` by a number you will get an error.  Use something like `K22=""`  instead of `ISBLANK`

Comment: Either with our without brackets IF(K22=""),"",SUM(K22*1013.25)),IF(M22=""),"",SUM(M22*33.8639)),IF(O22=""),"",SUM(O22*1.33322)) returns an error as Excel thinks theses are equations. I have previously tried IF(K22 <>"") and variations but i cannot get any to work! I am probably just not seeing the wood for the trees, might have another go tomorow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor the equation to nest properly

```
=IF(K22<>"",SUM(K22*1013.25),IF(M22<>"",SUM(M22*33.8639),IF(O22<>"",SUM(O22*1.33322),"")))
```

Comment: I get 'you've entered too many arguments for this function' setup like that?

Comment: Thank you Scott, so i had almost all the answers in almost all the wrong places!